# Shortest distance between 2 points

Tags: optimization

Ok, this problem might be trivial, but i'm a bit stuck.

A string with length 3m is shaped to an "L". Find the shortest distance between the 2 endpoints.

So what i've done is to draw the figure, and i can see that pythagoras is key here. But how do i find the shortest distance?

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the font used for the L.

Comment: Haha, i should put two lines under that answer and turn in

Comment: @Regret: more to the point, the font used for the L is the variable we're qualifying over when we say "the shortest".

Comment: @Steve: In many fonts, $\cal L$ is not displayed as two line segments perpendicular to each other.

Comment: @Regret: then we have a choice either to include all of them in our consideration, or else get the problem finished before the deadline ;-)

Comment: @Steve: We could also trivialize the problem by defining a font where $\cal L$ is a circle.

Comment: @Steve: Apologies if I seem rude, I find joy in what may be considered pedantry.

Comment: @Regret: not at all rude. I suspect the professor will mark it wrong if you come back and say "as far as the fonts on my PC are concerned, the distance is minimised for the Wingdings font", or whatever it might be. But he might also change the question in future, to clarify that the English phrase "shaped to an L" means something other than "shaped like any glyph used to represent the byte with value 76, in any font you can create".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $d$ be the distance between the two endpoints.

Let say that the angle of the $L$ shape is at distance $x$ from the first extremity. 
I suppose that the angle is $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

Then you have, with Pythagoras helping a bit:

$d=\sqrt{x^2+(3-x)^2}=f(x)$

$f'(x)=\dfrac{4x-6}{\sqrt{x^2+(3-x)^2}}$ which has an extremum for $x=\dfrac 32$. $f'(x)$ is negative for $x<\dfrac 32$ so the extremum is a minimum.

EDIT: typo modified, the angle is indeed $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and not $\pi$. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I'm not sure whether to upvote or downvote for using the word "extremum" so much.

Comment: @Laertes: Isn't that a bit extreme? :)

Comment: @Regret: I refuse to respond to that. Wait...

Comment: @Laertes If you hesitate, I can help you: upvote! ;-)... Since I have not english as my mother tongue, I have an excuse!

Comment: You probably want the angle to be $\pi/2$, not $\pi$ ;)

Comment: Fair enough, I suppose. Upvoting...

Comment: @LeonAragones I think you're right, but it doesn't seem to affect the argument.

Comment: If the angle is $\pi$ then the distance between endpoints is constant.

Answer (score 4):

From a purely analytic angle, we can let $l$ and $w$ be the length and width of the L, giving the equations $$l+w=3$$ and $$l^2+w^2=D^2$$ where $D$ is the distance between the endpoints. Substituting, we have $$w=3-l$$ and so $$l^2+(3-l)^2=D$$ $$2l^2-6l+9=D.$$ Since we want to minimize $D$, and we have a positive parabola, we find the vertex ${6 \over 2\cdot 2}=1.5$. Thus we have $l=w=1.5$ and so $D=1.5\sqrt 2\approx 2.12$.

Alternatively, we can note that the diagonal will always be smallest in a square of any rectangle, so $l=w=1.5$ and so on. Depends on your tastes.

Comment: "we can note that the diagonal will always be smallest in a square of any rectangle" -- the proof of which can in any case be the same as what you did to answer the problem directly, but with a named value in place of $3$.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes, this is essentially the rigorous proof of that fact; my point was that if we view the problem as asking, "What rectangle has the shortest diagonal relative to its perimeter?" we can intuitively see the answer without calculation (though also without rigor).